# Handling exceptions Java

Tags: java, minecraft

I am trying to make a chat server that communicates with my Minecraft client and that worked fine but I can not get the client to work with the server. This is the client

```
public class ClientChatHandler {
    public static ObjectOutputStream output;
    public static ObjectInputStream input;
    public static String message = "";
    public static String serverIP = "localhost";
    public static Socket connection;
}

public ClientChatHandler(String host){
    serverIP = host;
}

public static void startRunning(){
    try{
        connectToServer();
        setupStreams();
        whileChatting();
    } catch(EOFException eofException){
        Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.color  + "\247a[Server] Client terminated the connection.");
    } catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void connectToServer() throws IOException{
    Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.color + "\247a[Server] Attempting to connect.");
    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 1337);
    Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.color + "\247a[Server]         Connected to server.");
}

public static void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    try{
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); 
    } catch(NullPointerException  Exception){
        Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.color   + "\247a[Server] Error creating streams. Closing connection");
    } catch(IOException ioException){
        Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.color  + "\247a[Server] Error creating streams. Closing connection");
    }   
}

public static void whileChatting() throws IOException{
    do{
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.color  + message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
            Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.color  + "\247a[Server]  \2474ERROR! Connecting, closing sockets.");
        }
    }while(!message.equals("server - end"));
}

public static void closeCrap(){
    Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.color  +  "\247a[Server] Closing connection");
    try{
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void sendMessage(String message){
    try{
        output.writeObject(message);
        output.flush();
        Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.color +   message);
    } catch(IOException ioException){
    }
}

public static void showMessage(final String message){
    Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.addChatMessage(Methods.getLetterColor(Variables.ChatName Color) + Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.username + "\2477:\247f " + message);
}
```

Now I keep getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` of this:

```
output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
output.flush();
input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Sorry for the lack of information but minecraft crashes and I get a null pointer exception from the above code.

Here's some text:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.minecraft.src.ClientChatHandler.whileChatting(ClientChatHandler.Java:79)
at org.renivivious.GuiConsole.mouseClicked(GuiConsole.java:671)
at net.minecraft.src.GuiScreen.handleMouseInput(GuiScreen.java:198)
at org.renivivious.GuiConsole.handleMouseInput(GuiConsole.java:356)
at net.minecraft.src.GuiScreen.handleInput(GuiScreen.java:172)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runTick(Minecraft.java:1394)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runGameLoop(Minecraft.java:731)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:656)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
--- END ERROR REPORT 8e0635c8 ----------
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? Any error messages ?

Comment: Exceptions are being handled, so what exception do you get?

Comment: From what I see is that the line `new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 1337);` is throwing an IOException and thus its null (throwing an exception). Since you are catching the IOException (and sadly doing nothing :) you are missing the actual error. My suggestions is to put a break point at that line and see what exactly is the error. Or you can catch the IOException and print out the error message. You should always *do* something when you catch an exception.

Comment: You need to provide actual error messages, otherwise we're left to read your code and guess what's happening. Your question is missing all the important troubleshooting information that we're going to need to help determine if the problem is your network, your server, the code itself, a typo, etc. Please help us narrow it down more. Also, please add any followup information to the question itself rather than commenting here.

Comment: What line does the link actually appear?

Comment: I think that Cemre sees the problem. I think its the:
new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 1337);
I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: Your setupStreams() throws IOException, but before it can, you catch it and prevent it from being thrown.  Try deleting that catch block and see if the error messages become more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String serverIP = "localhost";


public ClientChatHandler.....
    serverIP = host;
```

Here's your error, you're initializing the variable `serverIP` but when you instantiate the class you load it with an empty string. You have 2 options in the constructor

1. Remove the variable `host` or
2. When you call the constructor, send as parameter `"localhost"`